# Wordpress category colors

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have just started developing Wordpress themes and plugins. I am now stuck with an objective, adding an option in the categories page of the Wordpress dashboard to change the categories color.
For example other than the category name, slug, description ecc. I want to have a color option with a color selector.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

You can create a new color picker custom field in wp-admin and assign it to show when editing the taxonomy.

You can then go into each category and select a color.

Then you can use the get_field() method to show the value on the frontend.